# Insert failed due to es time format failure

Tags: elasticsearch

[image]

It looks like the time format is the same, but the insertion failed. Why？

Answer (score 0):

You have one `S` too many in the format, it needs to be

```
HH:mm:ss.SSZ
```

If you change that, it will work

Comment: Using format `HH:mm:ss.SSZ`, sometimes it can work, but sometimes it doesn't

Comment: The time format in my other indexes is the same, but they can work normally. Is this the ES bug?

Comment: Can you provide examples where it works and others where it doesn't work?